# Compress Module for Express Server Not Zipping

Tags: node.js, express, server, compression, gzip

I have installed node.js and am running a simple express server on my local machine. I have included the compress module and make the call for app (instance of express) to use this module. After debugging, my request appears to be passing through the filter with the option to be encoded with gzip, but when transmitting the response it is not encoded. Are there other common reasons I am overlooking for why this is the case?

Please see request header and source code in images linked 
below. (It should be noted that *file 1* is actually being retrieved, but not encoded)

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A71DJ.png) 
[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktTEo.png)

Comment: Please use text for code instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

After several days of struggle, I have come to the conclusion that the issue was not with the server or the compression middleware, but rather a proxy that is used on the network I am on. The data was indeed sent as compressed (gzip), but the proxy was intercepting the response and decompressing it prior to reaching the browser. Thus, it appeared to have been sent decompressed (in the response header).

Helpful hint: Read thoroughly over the known issues!

c.f. https://github.com/expressjs/compression/issues/31